# Ending a function before I recursively call it again

Tags: javascript, recursion, return

```
function startGame(diff){
 if (diff === 'easy'){
  loadEasy();
 }
}

function loadEasy(){
 difficultyPage.style.display = 'none';
 game.style.display = 'block';
 medHardTemplate.style.display = 'none';
 easyTemplate.style.display = 'block';

 newGame.addEventListener('click', function(){
  changeDifficulty('easy');
 });

 colors = randomColorsArray(3);

 correctColor = colorToChoose(colors);
 colorRGB.innerHTML = correctColor;

 for (var i = 0; i < easySquares.length; i++) {
  //add colors to squares
  easySquares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];

 easySquares[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
  var clickedColor = this.style.backgroundColor;

  if(clickedColor === correctColor) {
    changeColorsOnWinEasy(correctColor);
    message.innerHTML = "Correct!"      
    again.textContent = "Play Again?"
    again.addEventListener('click', function(){
        again.textContent = "NEW COLORS";
        header.style.backgroundColor = "#232323";
        colorRGB.style.backgroundColor = "#232323";
        message.innerHTML = "";
        changeDifficulty('easy');
    });
}
else {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "#232323";
    message.innerHTML = "Wrong!"
 }
});
}
}
```

I don't know when to return the function so that I don't have many functions running at the same time if I spam the newGame button causing my app to lag. I added a return; at the end of the loadEasy function but that didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: what is called first? loadEasy or startGame?

Comment: This may be the most inefficient code I've seen to perform such a simple task.

Comment: startGame is called first

Comment: Coupd you give a brief overview of your game? Im not shure what the code should do...

Comment: If you only want to run a function once at a time, use a Boolean when you start, then switch it back when you end the function.

Comment: This combination of recursively binding an eventlistener makes no sense to me. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: basically its a color choosing game where the code loads colors into the squares, i posted all the code for loadEasy. I'm new at JS so please bare with me lol

Comment: to prevent spamming the clicks, disable/hide the button the first time it is clicked, then re-enable/show it after the game is over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may set a flag indicating the current gametype, then you dont need to rebind a button handler everytime, you just need to define the button as *start the current game*:

```
let gametype = "easy":

function startGame(diff){
  gametype = diff || gametype;
  if (gametype === 'easy'){
    loadEasy();
  }
  else {
    throw Error('unknown gametype: ' + gametype);
  }
}

function loadEasy(){
  //... Whatever  
}

newGame.addEventListener('onclick', function(){
  startGame();
});
```

So to start a game with the current gametype do:

```
startGame();
```

To start a different one, pass a parameter:

```
startGame("medium");
```

Comment: wow, that worked, thank you so much! why does JS read an empty parameter as false? Also that is clever OR logic, what helped you thinking in ways like that? was it a class or just experience?

Comment: @trippze an empty parameter is undefined and undefined is falsy. The or trick is called *short circuiting* and ive learned it through writing answers on SO... ;)